# In Next-Auth is possible use different providers but with the same e-mail?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

im building a nextjs application using next-auth. For now i have login with google, credentials and github.If i make login with google that contain the email "example@gmail.com" and then i logout, if i try make login with github but with a account that have the same email "example@gmail.com", i get the error: OAuthAccountNotLinked

In the database model that next-auth provides to us, User have relation with Accounts that is an array, so i think that would be possible have the sabe user but liked with 2 accounts. I forgot something or this is the default behavior?

My [...nextAuth].ts code

```
export const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const data = requestWrapper(req, res);
  return await NextAuth(...data);
};

export default handler;

export function requestWrapper(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
): [req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse, opts: NextAuthOptions] {
  const generateSessionToken = () => randomUUID();

  const fromDate = (time: number, date = Date.now()) =>
    new Date(date + time * 1000);

  const adapter = PrismaAdapter(prisma);

  const opts: NextAuthOptions = {
    // Include user.id on session
    adapter: adapter,
    pages: {
      signIn: "/login",
    },
    callbacks: {
      session({ session, user }) {
        console.log("AAAA");
        if (session.user) {
          session.user = user;
        }
        return session;
      },
      async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
        // Check if this sign in callback is being called in the credentials authentication flow. If so, use the next-auth adapter to create a session entry in the database (SignIn is called after authorize so we can safely assume the user is valid and already authenticated).
        if (
          req.query.nextauth?.includes("callback") &&
          req.query.nextauth?.includes("credentials") &&
          req.method === "POST"
        ) {
          if (user) {
            const sessionToken = generateSessionToken();
            const sessionMaxAge = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30; //30Daysconst sessionMaxAge = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30; //30Days
            const sessionExpiry = fromDate(sessionMaxAge);

            await adapter.createSession({
              sessionToken: sessionToken,
              userId: user.id,
              expires: sessionExpiry,
            });

            const cookies = new Cookies(req, res);

            cookies.set("next-auth.session-token", sessionToken, {
              expires: sessionExpiry,
            });
          }
        }

        return true;
      },
    },
    jwt: {
      encode: async ({ token, secret, maxAge }) => {
        if (
          req.query.nextauth?.includes("callback") &&
          req.query.nextauth.includes("credentials") &&
          req.method === "POST"
        ) {
          const cookies = new Cookies(req, res);
          const cookie = cookies.get("next-auth.session-token");
          if (cookie) return cookie;
          else return "";
        }
        // Revert to default behaviour when not in the credentials provider callback flow
        return encode({ token, secret, maxAge });
      },
      decode: async ({ token, secret }) => {
        if (
          req.query.nextauth?.includes("callback") &&
          req.query.nextauth.includes("credentials") &&
          req.method === "POST"
        ) {
          return null;
        }

        // Revert to default behaviour when not in the credentials provider callback flow
        return decode({ token, secret });
      },
    },
    // Configure one or more authentication providers
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    // debug: true,
    providers: [
      GithubProvider({
        clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID as string,
        clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET as string,
        profile(profile, token) {
          return {
            id: profile.id.toString(),
            name: profile.name || profile.login,
            image: profile.avatar_url,
            email: profile.email,
            role: Role.USER,
          };
        },
      }),
      GoogleProvider({
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID as string,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET as string,
        authorization: {
          params: {
            prompt: "consent",
            access_type: "offline",
            response_type: "code",
          },
        },
      }),
      CredentialProvider({
        name: "CredentialProvider",
        credentials: {
          email: { label: "Email", type: "text", placeholder: "" },
          password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
        },
        async authorize(credentials: any, _req): Promise<any | null> {
          const userInputs = {
            email: credentials.email,
            password: credentials.password,
          };

          const { user } = await loginCredentials(userInputs);

          if (user) {
            return user;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        },
      }),
    ],
  };

  return [req, res, opts];
}
```

Comment: Have you solved this one? Might as well share the answer if you did!

Answer (score 4):

What solved the issue for me was adding `allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true` which would look something like this:

```
   providers: [
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
      allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true,
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true,
    }),
   ]
```

Doing this should solve most of the errors around account linking, but I would definitely love to hear from somebody that has come up with a better solution to this.

More on this here: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/oauth#allowdangerousemailaccountlinking-option